# Android patternPath deeplinking

Tags: android, pattern-matching, deep-linking

I'm trying to implement deep linking in my application.

These are the 2 urls:

Url1 : http://www.example.com/games/randomtext-**game**-randomno

Url2 : http://www.example.com/games/randomno-**scores**/randomscore

As evident, the initial part of both the urls resolve to same pattern. Is there any way to differentiate between two patterns in this case so that each serves the requirement individually.
I have gone through various SO links and tried many patterns, but the problem is that the pattern selected for url1 automatically resolves url2 as well. *game* and *scores* are constants in the above urls so I want to differentiate using them. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Url1 : http://www.example.com/games/randomtext-game-randomno/

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.example.com"
                android:pathPattern="\\/games\\/.*game.*\\/.*"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Url2 : http://www.example.com/games/randomno-scores/randomscore

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.example.com"
                android:pathPattern="\\/games\\/.*scores\\/.*"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the links are different at the same level(after /games) then while parsing the uri you can do something like this:

```
Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
String category = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
```

category will be randomtext-game-randomno for Url1 and
randomno-scores for Url2.

More on getPathSegments() https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html

Comment: Your approach is correct, but this will require Java code. I was hoping to resolve this at xml level, but there doesn't seem a way to do so. Anyhow, I resolved my problem using a translucent activity, and resolving the deep links from it to route to the desired activity.